# How to write (Mygrammar)Visitor class on C# using Antlr4?

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr, grammar, qbasic

I've just started learning parsing. And i'm trying to make little `QBasic` compiler using Visual Studio(`c#`) and Antlr4. I've already made my grammar, and generated files like `MyGrammarBaseListener.cs MyGrammarLexer.cs ...`. Now, what should i do with VisualStudio? thanks:)

Furthermore here is my grammar:

```
grammar gram;

prog : command+;

command : maincommand
        | expressioncommand
        | flowcommand
        ;


//main
maincommand : printcommand
            | inputcommand
            ;
//PRINT "I am:", myname$, myage
//INPUT "What is your name?", yourname$
printcommand : print (IDINT | IDSTR | STRING) NL
             | print (IDINT | IDSTR | STRING) (comma (IDINT | IDSTR | STRING))* NL
             ;
inputcommand : input (IDINT | IDSTR) NL
             | input (STRING comma)? (IDINT | IDSTR) NL
             ;
print : PRINT;
input : INPUT;


//expression
//age = 17
//schoolname = "School"
expressioncommand : intexpression
                  | strexpression
                  ;
intexpression : IDINT equals (IDINT | INT) NL
              | IDINT equals (IDINT | INT) (OPERATORMATH (IDINT | INT))* NL
              ;
strexpression : IDSTR equals (IDSTR | STRING) NL
              ;

equals : EQUALS;


//flow
/* IF a > 3 THEN
PRINT a - 1
INPUT b
ENDIF
*/
flowcommand : ifelseflow
            | whileflow
            ;

ifelseflow : if conditionflow then NL dosomething+ (elseif conditionflow then NL dosomething+)* (else NL dosomething+)? endif NL;
whileflow : while conditionflow NL (dosomething)+ wend NL;
dosomething : command;
conditionflow : (INT | IDINT) OPERATORBOOL (INT | IDINT)
              | (INT | IDINT) equals (INT | IDINT)
              | (STRING | IDSTR) equals (STRING | IDSTR)
              ;
if : IF;
then : THEN;
elseif : ELSEIF;
else : ELSE;
endif : ENDIF;
while : WHILE;
wend : WEND;
comma : COMMA;


//LEXERS
COMMA : ',';
PRINT : 'PRINT';
INPUT : 'INPUT';
EQUALS : '=';
IF : 'IF';
THEN : 'THEN';
ELSEIF : 'ELSEIF';
ELSE : 'ELSE';
ENDIF : 'ENDIF';
WHILE : 'WHILE';
WEND : 'WEND';
INT : [0-9]+;
STRING : '"' .*? '"';
IDINT : [a-zA-Z]+([0-9]*);
IDSTR : [a-zA-Z]+([0-9]*)'$';
NL : '\n';
WS : [ \t\r]+ -> skip;
OPERATORMATH : '+' | '-' | '*' | '/';
OPERATORBOOL : '>' | '<' | '>=' | '<=';
```

Comment: Consider adding more tags to get the appropriate response. Also see [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and about tags [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Uncertain what you're asking here.  Are you asking how to install Visual Studio support for ANTRL4?  Or something else?  Or how to create Visitor or Listener classes?  Tell us what you've done.